# Mongoose - MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$eq'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

When I run the following Mongoose aggregate query, I get an error:

Query:

```
await Users.aggregate([
    { $eq: ["$bot", false] }
]);
```

Error:

```
MongoError: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: '$eq'
    at queryCallback (/root/Geola/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:248:25)
    at /root/Geola/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:532:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
```

Am I using it wrong?

MongoDB: 4.0.6
Mongoose: 5.4.13
Ubuntu: 16.04

Comment: What do you want the query to achieve?

Comment: @RichardLovell Just want to check if a field is equal, like the [`$eq` docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why my original method didn't work, or why this works any better, but here's what fixed it for me:

```
await Users.aggregate([
    { $match: { $expr: { $eq: ["$bot", false] } } }
]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$eq` operator matches documents where the value of a field equals the specified value.

```
{ <field>: { $eq: <value> } }
```

You can try this method to filter based on a condition

```
db.inventory.find( { bot: { $eq: false } } )
```

More details in [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/)

**When you use Aggregate. Documents enter a multi-stage pipeline that transforms the documents into aggregated results.**
You have to use match to pass the match pipeline in your case.

You can learn more about aggregate pipeline [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)